# Low Pass filter on a digital signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I am new to using matlab and signal processing in general and can't figure out how to implement a low pass filter. I have these digital signal that's a vector and would like to run it through a low pass fiter of 40hz or if at all possible a bandpass filter .53-40hz (12db/oct). I have access to the signal processing toolbox but can't figure out how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is more then one option to applying a digital filter in Matlab. The doc is very good, so it is a good starting point to look at it and follow the examples:

1. [Applying 1D digital filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html)
2. [Using `conv` for filtering using a FIR filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html)
3. [FIR filter design](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/fir1.html)
4. [IIR filter design](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/f9-131178c.html#bqmx1oi)